# Display volume label using Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

Is there an easy way to retrieve under Cygwin the volume label of an external disk or usb stick, given that I know the drive letter?

I know that I can do from my shell (actually zsh) i.e. a

```
cmd /c dir f:
```

and parse the output, but this is not only ugly, but also has the drawback that the output of the DIR command is language specific, i.e. I can't parse for certain keywords in the output.

I wonder if there maybe is a command in Cygwin which would provide the desired information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `csih`package:

```
$ /usr/lib/csih/getVolInfo.exe /cygdrive/d | grep Name
Volume Name        : <DATA>

$ /usr/lib/csih/getVolInfo.exe /cygdrive/e | grep Name
Volume Name        : <RECOVERY>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know by chance, where the programs in /usr/lib/csih are documented? I don't have a man page for it, and Google doesn't seem to find something useful on this topic either.

Comment: Only in the source. They are auxiliary binaries for `/usr/share/csih/cygwin-service-installation-helper.sh` . `getAccountName.exe` and `winProductName.exe` accept a `--help` . For what I know `getVolInfo.exe` just dumps the internal info of the disk or network share. You can always ask the author https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin-announce/2018-06/msg00021.html on the cygwin mailing list

Comment: Thank you it works, but only for partitions that are mounted on Windows under "My Computer". You can't read labels for unmounted ones with this command.

Comment: @Smeterlink you can probably use `/sbin/cfdisk /dev/sdX` to see the label from an Administrator account. with `X` the local disk you are interest in.